# ProgrammingError column Users_student.school does not exist in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've been struggling with this issue for hours now.
I have a model in my app which goes like this

```
class Student(models.Model):
school = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
field_of_study = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Student')
courses = models.ManyToManyField('StudentDashboard.Course', related_name="student_courses")
```

And whenever I try to view details of this class through django admin panel, I face the error ProgrammingError column Users_student.school

And if I comment school, that happens for field_of_study. And if that is commented too, It works fine. But I actually do need those 2 fields so I can't just comment them and go on.

Anyone knows a solution to this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

what is your admin class
if just register the model for admin
check your migration

Comment: My migrations are fine. I get no error when I do makemigrations and migrate